# Can I boot or virtualize an archived root partition without the associated root partition?

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, backup, disk-image

I’ve made a backup of my Linux system’s root partition before reinstalling the OS. I’ve now realized there’s critical data on the backup, but this data is only accessible via software installed on that backup, and I don’t know its structure, so I can’t copy it over.

I’ve tried to run this with `chroot`, but this has failed, since the program runs via Flatpak, which seems to require certain kernel-level components to be in place (I’d fixed /proc by `mount --bind`ing it, but it still refused to work).

Is there a way I could use my existing boot partition as the boot partition to my backup image or virtualize the backup image without a boot partition?

For reference, my Linux system is Pop!_OS 21.04, the pre-backup system was 20.10, both with kernel version 5.11.0, and both installed with the default settings (although my current root partition is encrypted, the old one is not).

Comment: I know nothing about Flatpak. However, why not install 20.10 and any specialised software in a VM on your current setup. You ought to be able to access your backup and extract the important data - provided the VM supports your backup hardware.

Comment: I don’t know which files are actually relevant to the info I need, since they’re kept in a format I don’t know (distributed into files), but I can try copying over as much data as possible

Comment: To use a file, or set of files, as a virtual root disk, you need to know its structure/format.  Therefore, the answer is maybe, but only if you know that structure. If you know the structure, you can probably access the critical data with other means. One thing I don't understand: Why do you use a backup tool that has no restore option?